# Chef is eaten and used in his dishes

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, short-films

I saw this movie around four years ago I think, it is a horror movie made up of like five short different stories that have nothing to do with each other, but I remember one of the stories in that movie.

In the beginning there is a boy on his bike who falls and cuts himself and his grandma kisses his cut and tastes the blood and start drinking more of it, for some reason this persons blood tastes very very good to everyone else, it then skips to when he is an adult and he is a chef with his food critics not liking the food and another dish he puts out he cuts himself and accidentally puts his blood on the dish and the critic thinks the food is amazing, he thinks that it’s anyone’s blood and not his so he kills his coworker and uses that blood the next time the critics come and they think the food is terrible, the chef then realizes it’s only his blood that works so every day he has been taking out his blood but her gets to weak to do it and his sous-chef which is a woman sees what he is doing and agrees to go with it, eventually they make love and what I remember is seeing the restaurant doing well and the chef locked up in a freezer missing limbs and flesh, and the sous-chef being pregnant knowing she can use that blood

In color, English language, 2000's maybe on forward

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: In color, English language, 2000's maybe on forward,

Comment: You might want to [edit] this information into the question...and perhaps use paragraphs at the same time. "Walls of Text" aren't likely to be received very well.

Answer (score 3):

It was a tv series on Crackle.com called [The Unknown](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2384747/), main actor Dominic Monaghan. I put the Amazon link [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CAZOIBK). Crackle put it all on once disk and turned it into a sort of movie, that Redbox rented for a while.

> Anthology about a man with a blog that searches for the truth behind supernatural phenomena and documents people's stories of their experiences with the unknown.